# Sorting through mysql table and order by amount

Tags: php, mysql, count, sql-order-by

I'm currently trying to create a list of 5 blog titles of mine, where they are ranked from 1 to 5, 1 being the most popular, while the 5 being the least popular. And how I am ranking them is through views. Now I already have the views working and thats in a table called blog_views, while the blog is called blog.

So what I'm trying to do is have PHP sort through how many views are recorded in blog_views through the blog id that's recorded in them, then list the blog title through which ever has many views, to the least amount of views. How would I be able to do that? I hope my question was clear!

I tried experimenting, but failed, because I couldn't find the right approach to this.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Here is the Schema of the two tables:

```
Blog{ blog_id, title, body, userinformation}

blog_views{ viewid, ip, time, blog_id, used}
```

Comment: What you're referring to is called a JOIN. I suggest you [read some tutorials](http://mysqljoin.com/)

Comment: Can you post the basic schema of the blog and blog_views tables?

Comment: Sure, ill add the schema of those two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, this `JOIN` should do it;

```
SELECT blog.blog_id, COUNT(blog_views.blog_id) as views 
FROM blog
LEFT JOIN blog_views 
  ON blog.blog_id=blog_views.blog_id
GROUP BY blog.blog_id
ORDER BY COUNT(blog_views.blog_id) DESC;
```

In short, select all blog/blog views combinations, group them by blog_id to be able to count the views per blog id, and finally order by the number of views, descending.

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a57d/1).

Comment: It returned blanks, nothing came out of it.

Comment: It might be my end, let me look through the code again. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Ah, so, I echoed out the ID, and that worked, but if I were to echo out the title, it wouldn't work. I want to echo out the title, I think I have to revise the code you gave me, but it worked perfectly though, thanks a lot!